# How do convert Range in cells on google sheets, for fonctions

Tags: function, google-sheets

So I have created some fonctions that need a cell as an argument, (they take the content of a cell and return me a number, which corresponds to the score for the question), what I want to do is add, all these numbers, and I'm looking for a way to do it without writting a tonne. My fonction is something like PERTINENCE_CALCUL(cell){return a number}. My specific function is that:

`PERTINENCE_CALCUL=IF(cell="Tout à fait en désaccord";0;IF(cell="Plutôt en désaccord";1;IF(cell="Légèrement en désaccord";2;IF(cell="Légèrement en accord";3;IF(cell="Plutôt d'accord";4;IF(cell="Tout à fait d'accord";5;"ERREUR !!!"))))))`

[Here is my spreadsheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7wIs.png)

But they only check the content of a specific cell, and I'd like to have a way to add the results other than just doing them all manually.
[This is how I do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M76FA.png)

And I've tried like `Somme(PERTINENCE_CALCUL(A2:A10)) or Somme(PERTINENCE_CALCUL(A2):PERTINENCE_CALCUL(A10))`

And none of them work.

Comment: You may check `LAMBDA()` function.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to description of the purpose and operation of this formula, provide some sample data and an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate a value based on the response to Form questions.

In this answer, there are two sheets:

- `Responses` - the form responses in the linked spreadsheet
- `Scores` - the sheet to calculate the response values.

Enter this formula in cell A2 of "Score":

`=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(Responses!A2:A),COUNTA(Responses!A1:1),LAMBDA(r,c,if(index(Responses!A2:J10,r,c)="Tout à fait en désaccord",0,if(index(Responses!A2:J10,r,c)="Plutôt en désaccord",1,if(index(Responses!A2:J10,r,c)="Légèrement en désaccord",3,if(index(Responses!A2:J10,r,c)="Plutôt d'accord",4,if(index(Responses!A2:J10,r,c)="Tout à fait d'accord",5,"Error")))))))`

---

**SAMPLE - Scores**

[image: scores]

---

**SAMPLE - Responses**

[image: responses]